# How to draw round edges with chart.js for line diagrams

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Basically chart.js draws pointed edges for line digrams like shown in the documentation: [chart.js line dagrams](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/line-boundaries.html)

[image]

If there are really big differences in data-values these edges become quite pointed and overdraw the values a lot and even overlap the points which show the correct value.

To avoid this I want to get rounded edges for lines (but not curved lines!), but I do not have any idea how to realize this.
Does anybody know a way to do it?

(The only workaround I found so far was to set tension to a very small value like e.g. 0.02 but that's really not the most accurate way...)

Best

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chart.js has an option, `borderJoinStyle`, for configuring the type of join used for line plots. The available values are `round`, `bevel`, or `miter`. The following [image from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineJoin) (as linked to by the [Chart.js documentation on this option](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html?h=elements#line-configuration)) illustrates the style of each value, respectively:

[image]

Example usage:

```
options: {
    elements: {
        line: {
            borderJoinStyle: 'round'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I want straight lines without any overdrawing at edges. Usually you can choose an angle threshold in any diagramm tool to avoid the described overdrawings of peaked edges. So using tension is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set tension value from 0, to > 0.

Doc: [documentation chart js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html?h=elements#line-configuration)

Example code:

```
options: {
    elements: {
        line: {
            tension: 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Not at all, friend!

Answer (score -3):

You can set in Options the lineTension to 0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUaiw.png)

Comment: `lineTension: 0` will make the edges more square